# why am I CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Hi I'm getting `CrashLoopBackOff`in my container.
Docker image is running fine in my laptop but I can run it in kubernetis

This my deployment code

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: react-app
    labels:
        app: jobstreet
spec:
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: jobstreet
            role: master
            tier: frontend
    replicas: 1

    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: jobstreet
                role: master
                tier: frontend
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: master
                  image: parthi922/reactapp:v2
                  command: [ 'sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
                  resources:
                      requests:
                          cpu: 500m
                          memory: 500Mi
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: react-app
    labels:
        app: jobstreet
        role: master
        tier: frontend
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
        - port: 3000
    selector:
        app: jobstreet
        tier: frontend
```

When I type `kubectl get logs` this I what I get

```
standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrvHU.png)

Comment: How did you build the image?  Do the image and your Kubernetes cluster have the same architecture (ARM vs. x86)?

Comment: Please provide the `Dockerfile` for the image you are using if possible.

Comment: did you try using '/bin/sh' instead of 'sh'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you get probably means that the image is not prepared for a different architecture.

You can check it using the following command:

```
$ docker image inspect parthi922/reactapp:v2 | grep "Architecture"
        "Architecture": "arm64",
```

Make sure your k8 nodes are `arm64` or build your image in a different architecture.